# Cast or Convert the Powerpoint.TextRange to a Word.Range

Tags: c#, vba, ms-word, vsto, powerpoint

[Short Question] :

How can I Cast or Convert a PowerPoint.TextRange to a Word.Range ?

[Longer description ] :

I'm trying to mark a selected text range as "Do Not Check Spelling",
in PowerPoint 2013, from my code. It's a PowerPoint Add-In written in C#,
but I could adapt it from any other sample in other language (VBA, VB, PowerShell...)

Of course doing it manually with the Review, Language Settings is working perfectly.

My code gets the selected range in a Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.TextRange
read from Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWindow.Selection.TextRange;

(I've also started some tests with a Microsoft.Office.Core.TextRange2)

These objects contain a LanguageID property. Setting it to msoLanguageIDNoProofing is ignored (other real languages work, though). It seems coherent with the GUI display, where there are two properties, the selected language and a separate checkbox to disable the Spell Check.

I've displayed the TextRange properties for two similar ranges, one with the "Do Not Check Spelling" setting set manually... and it seems there's not an evident difference on them.

So I found by chance the Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Range object. 
It contains both the LanguageID, and a separate NoProofing property... 
so probably PowerPoint is using this Word object when editing Ranges.

My question is, how can I Cast or Convert the Powerpoint.TextRange to a Word.Range ?

Comment: JC, thanks for posting this question. I'm at a similar situation with disabling proofing using VBA. Wondering if you ever managed to find a solution to this. Would you be able to update/share?

Comment: Unfortunately, I had to stop this project because of this problem and some similar ones.... waiting for a good hint to come. I'm sure there's a way to do it (Microsoft does it !), probably completely undocumented.

Answer (score 0):

These are entirely different objects. There is no direct conversion between these types. You can copy property values from one and set them on another. Or just use the Copy/Paste operations programmatically.

Comment: Mmm... I'd like to know how the PowerPoint GUI manages to set the property... as the property I think I need (.NoProofing) is not in the PowerPoint objects. I was also considering to get some upper-layer object (as .Selection), convert it, and go down again in the Word side...